# How I can debug the installed eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, plugins

I have installed some JAVA plugin to the Eclipse. This plugin does not provides the source files (as this plugin contains only a set of JAR files). So, right now I want to "reverse engineering", to debug this plugin (to understand how it does work).

I know that I can run the Eclipse (which includes this plugin) in a "server" mode and then it will wait the remote 'GDB' connection.

Also, I have heard that I can use the Intellij IDEA as an IDE to remote debugging, to debug that Eclipse (with its plugin). But a main issue is that I have not a sources of that Eclipse plugin and I can't open it in Intellij IDEA.

So, my question is: is it possible to debug the eclipse JAVA plugin which has not a sources? And, if yes, then, how I can do it?

BR,
Denis

Answer (score 0):

Using Intellij IDEA for this is nonsense--this is little different from debugging a plug-in when you *do* have the sources available, and plug-in developers have to do that all the time.

1) Install the Plug-in Development Environment. It's found in the Eclipse Project update site you should already have built-in.

2) Import the [plug-in into a project](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/import_wizards/import_plugins.htm?cp=4_3_9_2_0) in your workspace. Be sure to look for

3) Launch an Eclipse Application using a different workspace from the Debug menu.

This essentially takes what's in the [Target Platform preference page](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm?cp=4_1_5), adds the plug-in from your workspace, and runs a copy of Eclipse with all of that mixed together. It's a different JVM process and should have its own workspace directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, how to set break-points then? F.e. the imported binary plugins has not the sources. And the "Class File Editor" say that "Source not found", "attach source".

Comment: If there's no debug information included in the class files, and you lack sources, you can really only toggle on method entry them from the Outline view.